# Does the compiler optimize in this case?

Tags: c++, game-engine, compiler-optimization

I am using visual studio and are currently creating a game engine in c++, it's in 2D. The purpose is to learn modern game engine architecture and component based systems in general. This means that i have a very performance oriented mindset (even though performance isn't much of an issue when developing for 2D on modern hardware).

Would the compiler optimze something like this?

```
template<class T>
inline T & Scene::accessComponent(unsigned int id)
{
    if (dynamic_cast(T*) < Transform > ) {
        ...
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast(T*) < Collidable > ) {
        ...
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast(T*) < AnotherComponentType > ) {
        ...
    }

    etc ...
}
```

I heard that if a function enters the same logic gate on sequential calls the compiler can optimize for future calls. Does this work with templated functions aswell? Do the compiler optimize if T is of the same type on sequential calls?

I cant profile anything because currently the code is a mess, different parts of the engine that would allow for a accessComponent call are not implemented yet. So i am kind of in the planning phase.

Comment: You are describing branch prediction It's a feature of some computer architectures, independent c++.

Comment: At run time, template function instances are identical to non-template functions.

Comment: Put the code into https://godbolt.org/ and see for yourself. Although you really shouldn't need any casts for an ECS.

Comment: @nwp The reason i would use the described approach is because the developer would need to access one of the particular components using casting anyway, namely the scriptable. These are defined by the developer so the engine has no idea what the derived type is. Therefore it would make more sense for the dev to just use one general function to access all of the components.

Comment: You can make an ECS without making components inherit from a base class and without requiring casts which is much easier for the developer, results in much cleaner code and might even give you better performance because you don't need `dynamic_cast`s.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, so is it safe to assume that the code will be optimized? Are the architectures you describe widely used?

Comment: @nwp true, but the developer need to define components aswell, right (scripts)? In my design these are on the same "level" as the core components so that an entity can have an arbitrary number of scriptable components attached. How would one access these without casting?

Comment: @ojojkolol C++ standard doesn't specify any requirements for optimization. If you give us a concrete compiler and version, the specified flags, then we can make fairly accurate predictions for the optimization behaviour of that specific compiler and version.

Comment: Typically the developer writes something like `struct Speed{float speed;}; Speed s{3.14f}; Entity entity; entity.add(s);` and later on `for (auto &entity : System::get<Speed, Direction, Position>()){ entity.get<Position>() += entity.get<Direction>() * entity.get<Speed>();}`.

Comment: @nwp Aren't you using casting in that example?

Comment: No casting in that example, not even in the implementation. This doesn't work anymore if you want to write scripts from, say, Lua, because the types that Lua creates are not known at compile time. In this case you need to make a `struct Lua_type;` that can hold all lua types and then you will have to do some sort of type lookup when using those `Lua_type`s because you don't know what they contain at compile time.

Comment: @nwp okay, i don't know lua but i'l check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is something which certainly should not be done in performance-oriented code. It suffers from multiple branches. Logically, there are **at least** two branches with every dynamic_cast check: a branch generated by the compiler itself (to check RTTI) and a branch generated by your `if` statement.

Branch predictors in modern hardware are powerful, but limited. At the bare minimum, their quantity is limited, and than if the distribution of events is more or less uniform, they fail.

And even when branch prediction succeeds, you still loose some cycles on the branch calculation itself.

I see no reason for dynamic cast at all. Since your classes are already polymorphic, just call corresponding virtual methods.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this. I dont have polymorphic classes though (except for scriptable) so it might not count as an ECS. The reason being i dind't find any common behaviour except for the update, but this takes different arguments depending on component type.